# Angular 14: Animations not animating properly in my app but work perfectly in stackblitz demo

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm using Angular Animations on my portfolio and instead of animating in and out they just pop up and disappear.  I changed the timing to 9000ms to see if maybe it was happening too fast to notice and it pops up instantly when entering and delays for 9s before disappearing when leaving.  Here's how I have everything defined.

```
export const mobileNavAnimation = trigger('mobileNav', [
    transition(':enter', [
        animate('9000ms', keyframes([
            style({
                translate: '0px -600px',
                offset: 0
            }),
            style({
                translate: '0px 0px',
                offset: 1
            })
        ]))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
        animate('9000ms', keyframes([
            style({
                translate: '0px 0px',
                offset: 0
            }),
            style({
                translate: '0px -600px',
                offset: 1
            })
        ]))
    ])
])
```

I have the `BrowserAnimationsModule` imported into my `app.module.ts` file and I imported the animation into the `animations` array in my component's metadata.  I use it in my template by adding `@mobileNav` to the element.  I initially used `void =>*` and `* => void` before switching to `:enter` and `:leave` and still get the same results.

[This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z4h4ab?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fframe%2Fframe.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fanimation.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) demonstrates exactly what I'm doing and as you'll see when you run it, it works as expected.  Does anybody know why it might work on there but not in my local project?

Comment: do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: no I don't have any errors.